# How to obtain "Checkout Behavior Analysis" report with the API

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm trying to to use the Core Reporting API to get com information as it is displayed at the "Checkout Behavior Analysis report".

I tried to use the Shopping Stage dimension but it gives me strange information like:

```
CHECKOUT_1
CHECKOUT_2_WITHOUT_CHECKOUT_1
...
```

I need information from the following flow

```
Cart -> Identification -> Payment -> Sessions With Transactions
```

Does anyone knows which dimension I have to use to obtain this?

Answer (score 2):

After some deep investigation I found the answer. When you click on the bar at GA interface it shows the name of the Shopping Stage.